# Have UserDir enabled but also want to rewrite url if called differently

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver, httpd.conf

I am setting up a new server for our users to use have have personal webspace on. I have in my httpd.conf of apache the directives for UserDir as follows

```
UserDir disabled root
UserDir public_html
```

This has allowed `http://myserver/~user/` requests to work but I am also looking to set it up so the pages can be accessed via `http://myserver/users/username`.

How can this be done? I had thought about mod_rewrite rule but have thus far been unsuccessful.

EDIT:
Essentially I am looking to take the `http://myserver/users/username` requests and either point them or rewrite them to  `http://myserver/~user/`. whether it changes in the address bar is irrelevant at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have consulted some older colleagues of mine and we have found that the rule I was looking for was:

```
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)$ /~\$1 [R]
```

If I were using `Alias` matching I would need:

```
AliasMatch (^[A-Za-z0-9])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is somebody that managed to use rewrite rules to remove the tilde completely:
http://www.bit-integrity.com/2011/08/getting-rid-of-tilde.html

I've modified what they did to put the "users" directory in.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteLog logs/rewrite.log # Uncomment for rewrite logging
#RewriteLogLevel 3 # uncomment for verbose logging
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/users/([^/]+)
RewriteCond /home/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)(.*) /home/$1/public_html/$2
```

Here is a thread at WebmasterWorld.com where somebody wanted to redirect away from the version with the tilde: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4362132.htm

If you wanted to redirect away from the tilde version, you would have to use something like this.   These rewrite rules are meant to go into each users .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /~mysite
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(example\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The first part looks like what I need however it does not appear to be working as intended. I am still trouble shooting it but as of currently writing it does not rewrite `http://myserver/user/test/index.html` to `http://myserver/~test/index.html` it just states the page cannot be found

Comment: I put in `/users/` not `/user/`.  Also that rewrite rule is meant to work in your httpd.conf file not in a .htaccess file because the  rules start with /, make sure you are putting the rewrite rules in httpd.conf and restarting the server.

Comment: That was a typeo on my part. I am using `/users/`
Nothing is being logged to the log and browsers just return a 404 `The requested URL /users/test/index.html was not found on this server`

Comment: Thats as much help as I can provide then.  I hope you get another answer that works for you.

Comment: I think it is still the right path. Thank you for your assistance. IF I could up vote I would.